# Netbeans generated code settings

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting, auto-generate

I was wondering where can I change the way Netbeans generates code. For example, I want the opening bracket to be on a new line.

I've been looking in the [Tools] -> [Options] menu but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** should solve your problem. For any auto-generated code formatting that **Solution 1** won't solve, use **Solution 2**. Beware the *"Code Templates"* tab though, it has been relatively buggy for me in the past.

**Important Note:** Attempting to modify the *"Code Templates"* for the placement of braces won't work correctly because it's overridden by the preferences in **Solution 1**. Any changes to formatting wanted should first be attempted with **Solution 1**, as the *"Formatting"* tab in Netbeans takes precedence over the *"Code Templates"* tab.

**Solution 1:**

Go to `[Tools]` -> `[Options]` -> `[Editor]` -> `[Formatting]`. Choose the language you are using, then, for the `Category` drop down box, select `Braces`. Directly under that you'll see `Braces Placement`. You can modify the placement of the braces for a class declaration, method declaration, or "other". Options are:

- Same Line - places bracket on same line as class, method, or "other".
- New Line - places bracket on a new line under the class, method, or "other".
- New Line Half Indented - same as "New Line" with a half indention added.
- New Line Indented - same as "New Line" with a full indention added.

**Solution 2:**

Go to `[Tools]` -> `[Options]` -> `[Editor]` -> `[Code Templates]`. Choose the language you are using, then modify the templates according to what formatting you'd prefer.

For example, if Java is selected, I can scroll to the "pm" abbreviation and see how Netbeans generates private methods. Here is a incomplete but helpful *abbreviation-to-meaning* list for a few common Java abbreviations you might want to change.

- m - Method
- p - Private
- f - Final
- s - Static

Therefore, if you want to change the formatting for an auto-generated method that is listed as "private", you can change the formatting for the abbreviation "pm" in the "Expanded Text" area, which shows the auto-generation rules/formatting for a private method.

**Note:** Combinations of these letters can sometimes mean something different, for example "pr" is expanded to "private", but "prm" is listed as a protected method, not a private method.

Comment: More ***Code Templates*** for _NetBeans 8.0_ ?