# How to change auto-generated code templates in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

If I tell Netbeans to automatically generate code, let's say a constructor, I want all parameters to use the `final` modifier.

Currently:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
  // ...
}
```

What I want:

```
public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String address) {
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to change that in Netbeans, and if yes: where would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038930/netbeans-generated-code-settings

Comment: No duplicate, that is a different functionality in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to be possible out of the box. I have looked for "easy" configuration options for any of the auto-generated methods (constructor, get/setters, toString() etc) in (NetBeans 8.0.2):

1. Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates -> Java
2. Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion -> Java
3. Tools -> Templates -> Java
4. NetBeans Java Editor reference [documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html)

If such functionality cannot be found in any of the above, it's safe to assume it doesn't exist.

In the NetBeans documentation [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html) you can see an example of how to extend NetBeans with a custom code generator. That's one viable alternative, but it involves writing Java code that will generate Java code.

In summary, create a new NetBeans module :
File -> New Project -> NetBeans Modules -> Module

and then a custom generator by right-clicking on the module and
New -> Other -> Module Development -> Code Generator

You will have to go through NetBeans' source code for the current method that generates constructors.